# Log all incoming and outgoing requests using nc command

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface

I have a web server listening at 8080, I want to use the `nc` command to listen at port 80, so all incoming request and outgoing response are logged into two files, namely `inflow` and `outflow`.

I have followed the link at http://smaftoul.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/netcat-as-a-logging-tcp-proxy/, not work as expected.

```
 cat proxypipe | nc -l -p 80 | tee -a inflow | nc localhost 81 | tee -a outflow 1>proxypipe
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_protocol]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look at the help output netcat is giving you

```
usage: ... [-p source_port] ...
       ... [hostname] [port[s]]
```

The `-p` option to netcat species the source port, which you generally don't care about.  If you remove the `-p`, it should work just fine:

```
nc -l 80
```

At least, this will make netcat listen for connections on port 80.  Whether this will make your logging proxy work or not I can't say.